# While I'm trying to insert data into my access database it's showing Exceptionhandler error: Syntax error INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, exception, syntax-error

I'm trying to insert values into my MS Access database but the exception handler shows an error:

> Syntax error in "INSERT INTO" statement.

But I have checked and found no error. How to fix such error?

I have tried to fix it with command, also with parameters, and checked thousand times but I found nothing error in my code.

```
private void Save_bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CompanyDetails([column name]) VALUES ('"+textboxname.Text+"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Data saved!");
}
```

I expect that message box will show "Data Saved". But it's instead showing error on the line

```
ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and also syntax of `INSERT INTO` statement.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @marc_s I'm a beginner here and also a beginner in c# so can you please help me to understand those parameters. e.g giving an example!

Comment: How about this Krishna? After setting CommandText add Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText). Take this value and paste it into Access query designer, you will get a better error message...plus, don't accept user text to use in sql as marc_s mentioned

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that syntax that is apparent from what you have shown.  The value of `textboxname` you are using could be the problem, or `[column name]` is not really your column name and you are using something invalid. Do as @SimonWilson says and look at the value of `CommandText` just before you `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: `I have tried to fix it with ... parameters` You should post that code because gluing data and text together to make a query has been the wrong way for a long time.  This type of problem is easily fixed using Parameters

Answer (score 0):

The structure of companyDetails **([column name]) is incorrect**. '[Column name]' sounds static.

Do you think you forgot to use the name of your column?

Regards,

Comment: No. I did not! sir. @Ufuktan

Comment: What is the name of the column you want to add in the "companyDetails" table? Column name not added on this code. Additionally, are you sure you fill in non-nullable columns in the company Details table? @KrishnaGhosh